Libre office writer , .doc files not responding about 2 minutes
I am using Libre office Suit 24.2.1 in my All ubuntu 22.4 operated Dell i5 desktops. While opening .doc files, it becomes none responsive for about 1 to 2 minutes. The same thing is happening while I am trying to configure printers in ubuntu 22.4 installed other new Dell i5 Desktops also. Can any one help me ?.

ask ubuntu required you to focus on one question per post. Have you istalled LO as deb or snap? {edit] your question accordingly

Do you have swap? free will tell you.

Yes I have. With built in  Ubuntu 22.04 lts
